# Python3 regex on bytes variable

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to perform a regex substitution on a bytes variable but I receive the error

```
  sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

Here is a small code example to reproduce the problem with python3:

```
import re

try:
    test = b'\x1babc\x07123'
    test = re.sub(b"\x1b.*\x07", '', test)
    print(test)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Note: the `*` quantifier is greedy: it tries to match as much as possible. For example, provided your bytestring is `\x1babc\x07123\x07` the result after substitution will be empty string. Adding `?` after the quantifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched. (from https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When acting on bytes object, all arguments must be of type `byte`, including the replacement string. That is:

```
test = re.sub(b"\x1b.*\x07", b'', test)
```

Answer (score 7):

Your replacement value must be a `bytes` object too:

```
re.sub(b"\x1b.*\x07", b'', test)
#                     ^^^
```

You can't replace matching bytes with a `str` object, even if that is an empty string object.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = b'\x1babc\x07123'
>>> re.sub(b"\x1b.*\x07", b'', test)
b'123'
```